# What are the exact semantics of "ENDIR IRPAUSE" command?

Tags: jtag

Consider the following SVF file snippet.

```
ENDIR IRPAUSE;
SIR 10 TDI (002);
```

Once the data have been shifted into the instruction register, should the state machine go

```
IRSHIFT->IREXIT1->IRPAUSE
```

without going through `IRUPDATE`? Or should it go

```
IRSHIFT->IREXIT1->IRPAUSE->IREXIT2->IRUPDATE
->DRSELECT->IRSELECT->IRCAPTURE->IREXIT1->IRPAUSE
```

as if `STATE IRSELECT` was issued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested both possibilities and configuring the device I have at hand works with the former state sequence, whereas it fails for the latter. Lacking any "official" interpretation of the specification, I'm going to go with this empirical evidence.